# Scalability of Remote EJB vs Local EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, data-access-layer

I have been trying to decide between a Local and Remote EJB for a Data Access Layer.  Through a lot of research, it seems like the general consensus is that if I want scalability, I should use a Remote EJB.

What does that mean though?  I can not find anything that explicitly shows why Remote EJB can scale and Local can not.

Comment: remote vs local has absolutely nothing to do with scalibility. It only referres to whether or not the EJB can be accessed from a remote call or a local call. In practice Remote is not ever used but in rare cases because all the logic is usually in the same app server so making remote calls adds latency and decreases performance for the general cases.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you got that general consensus.

Remember [Fowler's First Law of Distributed Objects](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FirstLaw.html).

You have to make a call over the network from a Java object to a relational database (unless it's an in-memory database).  Why would adding an additional hop from your session bean to a remote object be faster or more scalable?

Besides, scalability is determined by a lot more than this.

I'd say your consensus is wrong: prefer local if you can.

Comment: Although I know it's wrong, I recognise the sentiment from a decade ago. People thought putting business logic on a separate server would help with scaling, since you could then add a more heavyweight server for business logic and many additional nodes for handling web requests. This idea was very pervasive. I had talk for hours to get it out of people's heads back then.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is:

- LocalBean: 
  This will run at the same EJB Container as its caller. This means every single call is faster compared to the remote call. But it will stay at the same servernode even if it runs out of ressources.
- RemoteBean:
  This will run at one Node in the EJB cluster. It will jump to another node, if one is running auf of ressources. You can also add nodes to scale up.

**edit**
If you want your beans just to edit a Database, use LocalBeans..
as @duffymo wrote

Comment: If one is running auf of resources, it's likely that the Servlet layer has already run out of resources, and your load-balancer will have routed the request to another node. In most cases EJBs do too little work for this to pay off. Things like databases, search engines, messaging systems, job servers etc can often (almost always) benefit from their own server, but EJBs rarely.

Answer (score 0):

I assume we're talking a classic Java EE scenario:

```
 client (usually browser) ----> Servlet ----> EJB ----> DB
```

In which case we could either co-locate Servlet and EJB, and use local interfaces or have Servlet and EJB in separate layers and hence need remote interfaces - of course using a remote interface would require an extra network hop, however it could conceivably give benefits.

Consider first scaling the local scenario. Servlet/EJB engine runs out of steam, so we deploy another one, get more power (obviously some sprayer in front of the servlet must distribute the work. We need more power, add yet more Servlet/EJB layers. Just fine it scales. But ...

Suppose that our EJB layer happens to be really really heavy, perhaps doing some complex computation after fetching the data. To achieve our required performance we scale the combined Servlet/EJB layer, BUT we didn't need all those copies of the Servlet engine, they are hardly doing any work, all the work is in the EJB layer, we consume memory and other resources for no reason. In such a scenario using remote EJBs might give us a win, we can deploy independently, getting as many copies of the servlet engine and EJB engine as we need, and the cost of the remote hop may be negligible in comparison with the complex computation cost.

Comment: In practice the last example is rare. EJBs do little work, and if we typically need more power when more requests come in,which means we need both extra Servlets, JSF backing beans AND EJB beans. Maybe there sometimes is a single bean (or a few) that do heavy computations. If that is so; put only these on an extra server. But OP asks to put ALL EJBs by default on a remote server in order to scale and that is just not right. Most EJB beans typically just coordinate a transaction and several DB calls.

Comment: Agree. The point about only separating the "special" EJBs is important.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understand the accepted answer but the use of remote EJB not always mean distributed business logic in more than one server.

A good example of scalability using remote EJB is [API Gateways](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html). You can configure an API gateway as EJB client (a single WAR, per example) to use the remote EJB from different servers (EARs, per example) that contains the business logic.

Using this idea, you can have more than one server to provide remote EJBs for the API gateways, distributing the work for all the servers in each `lookup`.